# How do you intercept all put/remove/modify calls to a Map using a ForwardingMap?

Tags: java

I tried extending ForwardingMap because I wanted to intercept all calls to put/putAll/remove/clear and also intercept calls on Iterators of KeySet/EntrySet/Values such as remove/Map.Entry.setValue() etc.

It took me a while to figure out what methods to override and how - especially the entrySet() method. Some of the JavaDocs on standard* are confusing at best.

Here's my code. It seems to be correct, can someone review it? Perhaps this could be included in the Forwarding* examples to help others?

There's a main method at the bottom to run the test:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ForwardingIterator;
import com.google.common.collect.ForwardingMap;
import com.google.common.collect.ForwardingMapEntry;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

import java.util.*;

/*
* Author: Ashwin Jayaprakash
*/
public class CatchAllMap<K, V> extends ForwardingMap<K, V> {
    HashMap<K, V> delegate = new HashMap<>();

    public CatchAllMap() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<K, V> delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object object) {
        System.out.printf("Call to remove [%s]%n", object);

        return super.remove(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        System.out.printf("Call to clear%n");

        super.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        System.out.printf("Call to put [%s : %s]%n", key, value);

        return super.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(java.util.Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map) {
        System.out.printf("Call to putAll [%s]%n", map);

        super.putAll(map);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        System.out.printf("Call to keySet%n");

        return new StandardKeySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        System.out.printf("Call to values%n");

        return new StandardValues();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        System.out.printf("Call to entrySet%n");

        final Iterator<Entry<K, V>> forwardingIterator = new ForwardingIterator<Entry<K, V>>() {
            Iterator<Entry<K, V>> actual = delegate.entrySet().iterator();

            @Override
            protected Iterator<Entry<K, V>> delegate() {
                return actual;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                System.out.printf("Call to entrySet.iterator.remove%n");

                super.remove();
            }

            @Override
            public Entry<K, V> next() {
                final Entry<K, V> entry = super.next();

                System.out.printf("Call to entrySet.iterator.next[%s]%n", entry);

                return new ForwardingMapEntry<K, V>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Entry<K, V> delegate() {
                        return entry;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public V setValue(V value) {
                        System.out.printf("Call to entrySet.iterator.entry[%s].setValue[%s]%n", entry, value);

                        return super.setValue(value);
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        return new StandardEntrySet() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
                return forwardingIterator;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CatchAllMap<String, String> map = new CatchAllMap<>();

        map.put("Homer", "Simpson");
        map.put("Ned", "Flanders");
        map.put("Carl", "Carlson");
        map.put("Lenny", "Leonard");
        map.put("Montgomery", "Burns");
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);

        map.remove("Ned");
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);

        map.putAll(ImmutableMap.of("Bart", "Simpson", "Chief", "Wiggum"));
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);

        System.out.println("Keys:");
        for (Object o : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("    " + o);
        }
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);

        System.out.println("Values:");
        int x = 0;
        for (Iterator valueIterator = map.values().iterator(); valueIterator.hasNext(); x++) {
            Object next = valueIterator.next();

            System.out.println("    " + next);

            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Removing..." + next);
                valueIterator.remove();
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);

        System.out.println("Entries:");
        x = 0;
        for (Iterator<Entry<String, String>> entryIterator = map.entrySet().iterator(); entryIterator.hasNext(); x++) {
            Entry<String, String> entry = entryIterator.next();

            System.out.println("     " + entry);

            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Modifying..." + entry);
                entry.setValue(entry.getValue() + "... Haha!");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Removing..." + entry);
                entryIterator.remove();
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);

        map.clear();
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);

        map.putAll(ImmutableMap.of("Stan", "Marsh", "Eric", "Cartman"));
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);

        map.keySet().clear();
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);

        map.putAll(ImmutableMap.of("Peter", "Griffin", "Brian", "Griffin"));
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);

        map.values().clear();
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);

        map.putAll(ImmutableMap.of("Darth", "Vader", "Hans", "Solo"));
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);

        System.out.println("Entries:");
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("    " + entry);
        }

        System.out.println("Entries again:");
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("    " + entry);
        }

        map.entrySet().clear();
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", map.delegate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Co-author of `ForwardingMap` here.  (You should probably be using `codereview.stackexchange.com`, FYI.)  Suggestions for how to improve the `standardXXX` Javadocs would be appreciated, by the way.

First off, not using generics is a *bad plan*.  Seriously.  Use them.  If I was reviewing your code forrealz, I would refuse to do any more reviewing until you fixed that first.

Secondly, your overridden `entrySet` will only let you do one full iteration, and then it won't support iteration any more.  You should be creating a fresh iterator for every call to `StandardEntrySet.iterator()`.

Those are the most prominent problems I can identify off the top of my head.

Comment: Thx. I had missed the iterator instance. About Generics, agree..I always use them. Just wasn't sure if stackoverflow would barf over the angle brackets

Comment: Web searches for how to use this class brought me here, but unfortunately, I don't feel you've answered the OP's question.
¶
For my application, I want to use this to delegate to another map and do some key translation. The map I want to back is unmodifiable, so I only care about reading operations. Do I just need to override get() and containsKey(), or others, too? Maybe I just haven't found the docs.
¶
Having said that, this is an 'I love the Internet' moment: the co-author of a class gets to code-review code that implements it: a wonderful learning experience for both engineers. Awesome.

Comment: Are you changing the key type?  If so, `ForwardingMap` isn't going to do the job properly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I figured this out and I've implemented what I want just using AbstractMap. In addition to entrySet(), I just had to override get(Object), containsKey(Object) and isEmpty(), and only to aid efficiency.